# Disconnect Websocket on server side based on a token passed from UI

Tags: java, spring-mvc, websocket, stomp

My aim is to connect browser clients having proper headers with the server. I pass these headers from StompClient.

My UI code in which i passed **token** in the header is

```
function connect() {
    var socket = new SockJS('/websocket/api/add');
    stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    stompClient.connect({"token" : "12345"}, function(frame) {
        setConnected(true);
        console.log('Connected: ' + frame);                
    });
}
```

In backend i am able to read the headers in the *preSend()* method of **ChannelInterceptorAdapter**

```
@Override
public Message<?> preSend(Message<?> message, MessageChannel channel) {
    MessageHeaders headers = message.getHeaders();
    System.out.println("preSend : HEADERS : {}" + headers);
    return super.preSend(message, channel);
}
```

But here i am not able to close the wesocket session. How can we do that?

Also i was able to close the websocket session but i couldn't receive the headers in *afterConnectionEstablished()* method of **WebSocketHandlerDecorator**

```
public void configureWebSocketTransport(final WebSocketTransportRegistration registration) {
    registration.addDecoratorFactory(new WebSocketHandlerDecoratorFactory() {
        @Override
        public WebSocketHandler decorate(final WebSocketHandler handler) {
            return new WebSocketHandlerDecorator(handler) {
                @Override
                public void afterConnectionEstablished(final WebSocketSession session) throws Exception {   

                    session.close(CloseStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
                    super.afterConnectionEstablished(session);
                }
            };
        }
    });
    super.configureWebSocketTransport(registration);
}
```

Can someone guide me how can i close the websocketsession based on the header we pass from UI at server side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try sending the client's token to the server through a message when connection established, then let the server save that session into a map, whose key is the corresponding token.

So when you want to close a session by its token, you can query for the session from that map using the token.

---

Sample Code:

Save the session with its token:

```
@Override
public void handleMessage(WebSocketSession session, WebSocketMessage<?> message) throws Exception {
    String messageToString = message.getPayload().toString();
    if (messageToString.startsWith("token=")) {
        tokenToSessionMapping.put(messageToString.substring("token=".length()));
    }
    // Other handling message code...
}
```

Close the session by token:

```
WebSocketSession sessionByToken = tokenToSessionMapping.get(token);
if (sessionByToken != null && sessionByToken.isOpen()) {
    sessionByToken.close(CloseStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);
}
```

And other things to notice:

1. Since the `tokenToSessionMapping` is static and is shared among sessions. You should use a thread-safe implementation such as ConcurrentHashMap.
2. When the session is closed, you'd better remove the corresponding entry from the map `tokenToSessionMapping`. Otherwise the map size will just keep growing. You can do this by the override method `afterConnectionClosed()`.

   ```
   @Override
   public void afterConnectionClosed(WebSocketSession session, CloseStatus status) throws Exception {
       Log.info("Socket session closed: {}", status.toString());
       String foundKey = null;
       for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : tokenToSessionMapping.entrySet()) {
           if (Objects.equals(entry.getValue(), session)) {
               foundKey = entry.getKey();
           }
       }
       if (foundKey != null) {
           tokenToSessionMapping.remove(foundKey);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing me in the right direction :)